# App crashing when using .setText - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm  still new to Kotlin so I don't really know why it crashes when using setText. What I want is to use the textViewDetection variable from the MainActivity and set that variable text on the ObjectDetectorHelper.kt

I'm referencing the Main Activity to my ObjectDetectorHelper.kt

Here's the code on MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    public lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    public lateinit var textViewDetection: EditText

    override fun onCreate(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)
        textViewDetection = activityMainBinding.editText

    }
}
```

ObjectDetectorHelper.kt

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.CompatibilityList
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.Rot90Op
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.BaseOptions
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.Detection
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.MainActivity

class ObjectDetectorHelper(
  var threshold: Float = 0.5f,
  var numThreads: Int = 2,
  var maxResults: Int = 3,
  var currentDelegate: Int = 0,
  var currentModel: Int = 0,
  val context: Context,
  val objectDetectorListener: DetectorListener?
) {
    val setMainActivity = MainActivity()
    //val Button = findViewById(R.id.dete)
    //al detectionResult = MainActivity().detectionTextView

    // For this example this needs to be a var so it can be reset on changes. If the ObjectDetector
    // will not change, a lazy val would be preferable.
    private var objectDetector: ObjectDetector? = null

    init {
        setupObjectDetector()
    }

    fun clearObjectDetector() {
        objectDetector = null
    }

    // Initialize the object detector using current settings on the
    // thread that is using it. CPU and NNAPI delegates can be used with detectors
    // that are created on the main thread and used on a background thread, but
    // the GPU delegate needs to be used on the thread that initialized the detector
    fun setupObjectDetector() {
        // Create the base options for the detector using specifies max results and score threshold
        val optionsBuilder =
            ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.builder()
                .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
                .setMaxResults(maxResults)

        // Set general detection options, including number of used threads
        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder().setNumThreads(numThreads)

        // Use the specified hardware for running the model. Default to CPU
        when (currentDelegate) {
            DELEGATE_CPU -> {
                // Default
            }
            DELEGATE_GPU -> {
                if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
                    baseOptionsBuilder.useGpu()
                } else {
                    objectDetectorListener?.onError("GPU is not supported on this device")
                }
            }
            DELEGATE_NNAPI -> {
                baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
            }
        }

        optionsBuilder.setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())

        val modelName =
            when (currentModel) {
                MODEL_CUSTOM -> "detect.tflite"
                // -> "mobilenetv1.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV0 -> "efficientdet-lite0.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV1 -> "efficientdet-lite1.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV2 -> "efficientdet-lite2.tflite"
                else -> "detect.tflite"
            }

        try {
            objectDetector =
                ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelName, optionsBuilder.build())
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            objectDetectorListener?.onError(
                "Object detector failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )
            Log.e("Test", "TFLite failed to load model with error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun detect(image: Bitmap, imageRotation: Int) {
        if (objectDetector == null) {
            setupObjectDetector()
        }


        // Inference time is the difference between the system time at the start and finish of the
        // process
        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        // Create preprocessor for the image.
        // See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/
        //            lite_support#imageprocessor_architecture
        val imageProcessor =
            ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(Rot90Op(-imageRotation / 90))
                .build()

        // Preprocess the image and convert it into a TensorImage for detection.
        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(image))

        val results = objectDetector?.detect(tensorImage)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        objectDetectorListener?.onResults(
            results,
            inferenceTime,
            tensorImage.height,
            tensorImage.width)
        //HERE IS THE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        if (results != null) {
            setMainActivity.textViewDetection.setText("pio")
        }

    }

    interface DetectorListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
          results: MutableList<Detection>?,
          inferenceTime: Long,
          imageHeight: Int,
          imageWidth: Int
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val DELEGATE_CPU = 0
        const val DELEGATE_GPU = 1
        const val DELEGATE_NNAPI = 2
        const val MODEL_CUSTOM = 0
        //const val MODEL_MOBILENETV1 = 1
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV0 = 2
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV1 = 3
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV2 = 4
    }
}
```

I tried using companions and using the public variables itself on the other file but all still gave an error. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> val setMainActivity = MainActivity()

This is not going to work. You can not instantiate an activity class like a regular class. Activities are specifically managed by the Android framework, which is responsible for their instantiation and lifecycle management

It's best to update the textview inside the activity itself and `ObjectDetectorHelper` class can just emit the string as [kotlin flow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow) that the activity can subscribe
or

 you can just use the `objectDetectorListener` callback parameter of `ObjectDetectorHelper`

Examples:
**Using the `objectDetectorListener` callback:**
In ObjectDetectorHelper

```
//Move the ff to MainActivity
//if (results != null) {
//        setMainActivity.textViewDetection.setText("pio")
// }
```

In MainActivity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     //your other codes

     val objectDetectorHelper = ObjectDetectorHelper(
          context = this,
          objectDetectorListener = object:DetectorListener{
                override fun onResults(results, _, _, _){
                   if (results != null) {
                      textViewDetection.setText("your text")
                  }
                 }
                override fun onError(error){}
                  
          }
      )


}
```

**Using kotlin flow:**
In ObjectDetectorHelper

```
val detectionTextStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<String>("")

//your other codes
if (results != null) {
      detectionTextStateFlow.value = results[0].categories[0].label
 }
```

In MainActivity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     //your other codes

     //should instantiate ObjectDetectorHelper before the following:
     val objectDetectorHelper = ObjectDetectorHelper(context=this, objectDetectorListener = null)

     lifeCyclecScope.launch{
            objectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow
                 .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
                 .collect{
                     textViewDetection.setText(it)
                  }
      } 

}
```

You can just remove DetectorListener parameter if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I have no clue to "Kotlin flow", does this solve the problem which is that I want to insert the detected object name on the EditText

Comment: It should. I'll provide a simple example that maybe useful to you.

Comment: I've tried it out but objectDetectorHelper was not returning anything. I'm using kotlin flow

Comment: Try to check/log results if it's not null

Comment: Am I doing this right on ObjectDetectorHelper? I put this inside the fun detect()

`fun main() = runBlocking {
                 launch{
                    //emitObject(results[0].categories[0].label)
                     detectionTextStateFlow.emit(results[0].categories[0].label)
                }
            }
            main()`

Comment: You don't have to do that. You can just value instead of emit `detectionTextStateFlow.value = results[0].categories[0].label`. See updated anwer.

Comment: It now returns a value but only occurs one time. I'll try again later. But thank you, you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Good thing you're using kotlin, the worst part is I'm not close to a computer. But I strongly advise you to decouple "android view" code from "business logic".

1. In your initializer, like below `objectDetectorListener`, and something like `onSetTextAction: (String) -> Unit`
2. Or make a public function, and let the crash be caught in the android exception handler, and you will know better if the crashes are from your implementation helper, or from android's lifecycle.

Then in your main activity, or where the helper is called, you can do:

`ObjectDetectorHelper(...){ binding.editTextView.text = it`

And calling mainActivity like that is dangerous, try to keep as much android out of the helper as possible. That class is not extending to what the mainActivity needs.

Comment: Thank you but it seems I can't do the 'ObjectDetectorHelper(...){ binding.editTextView.text = it' part